# Suma de valores de tablas que no tienen relación en laravel 5.3: stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema con laravel 5.3.

Mi problema ha surgido al obtener un valor de una tabla y querer sumarlo con otro valor de otra tabla que no tiene relación con la anterior tabla, me da el error siguiente:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int.

Mi controlador:

[image: Mi controlador es el siguiente:]

Comment: Hola @Anddy. Por favor publica tu código como texto, no como imagen. Pensemos en personas con problemas de vista o en pantallas las que no se defina bien la imagen, como celulares. Además, ¿de dónde sale `$sumact`?

Comment: Hola @Mariano, no había pensado en lo que me dices de la imagen, lo arreglaré. $sumact es $sumaActividad, es la misma variable, un error de escritura pero que no afecta al error principal de la suma

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que la consulta esté funcionando bien y entregue el resultado esperado, deberías poder acceder con:

```
$suma = $sumaPagos->suma;
$sumact = $sumaActividad->sum;
```

O si lo conviertes a un arreglo:

```
$suma = $sumaPagos['suma'];
```

Comment: Las consultas funcionan bien y cada una me da un valor. Lo que necesito es la suma de esos dos valores: ' el total' y enviar ese total a la vista